# How to iterate over a big Oracle database using python and jdbc-driver and store modified record values in another table?

Tags: python, database, oracle, jdbc

I have an Oracle DB with over 5 Million rows with columns of type varchar and blob. In order to connect to the database and read the records I use python 3.6 with a JDBC driver and the library JayDeBeApi. What I am trying to achieve is to read each row, perform some 
operations on the records (use a regex for example) and then store the new record values in a new table. I don't want to load all records in the memory, so what I want to do is to consequently fetch them from the database, store the fetched data, process it and then add it to the other table. 
Currently I fetch all the records at once instead for example first 1000, then the next 1000 and so on. This is what I have so far:

```
statement = "... a select statement..."
connection= dbDriver.connect(jclassname,[driver_url,username,password],jars,)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(statement)
fetched = cursor.fetchall()
for result in fetched:
    preprocess(result)
cursor.close()
```

How could I modify my code to fetch consequently and where to put the second statement which inserts the new values in the other table?

Comment: why use `fetchall()` instead of just iterating over `cursor`?

Comment: JDBC has the concept of fetch size, which allows to avoid loading all the data. If your library allows you to iterate over the cursor (ie without calling `fetchall()`), then you should in theory be able to iterate over all entries and do your own local batching or go for the finest one-by-one processing.

Comment: JayDeBeApi doesn't seem to have implementation of iteration over cursor, which is very unfortunate, @IvanVinogradov

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `fetchall()` is a bad idea in this case, as it loads all the data into the memory.

In order to avoid that you can iterate over `cursor` object itself:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
for row in cur:  # iterate over result set row by row
    do_stuff_with_row(row)
cur.close()
```

Comment: I will try that out! In order to call the insert statement for the new table ,can I do it with the same cursor object?

Comment: It didn't work, because the cursor object is not iterable in the jayDeBeeApi implementation

Comment: That's strange because [they say](https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi#jaydebeapi---bridge-from-jdbc-database-drivers-to-python-db-api) they support [DB API 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-objects), which clearly provides tools for iterating over cursors (`Cursor.next()`, `Cursor.__iter__()`)

Comment: SInce I am using python 3.6 I had to install the JayDeBeApi3  https://github.com/andreasnuesslein/JayDeBeApi3 which probably lacks this kind of implementation

Comment: What I see is that  cursor._rs gives back an oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@ object .

Comment: Okay...what I did was to use while cursor._rs.next():

Comment: With cx_Oracle queries, don't forget to tune http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.arraysize to reduce "round-trips"